# Does there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $5^n-2^n$ is a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, exponential-diophantine-equations

I checked up to $n\leq 100000$ then found no example. So I suspect that there doesn't exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $5^n-2^n$ is a perfect square.
Then I tried to prove by modular arithmetic, but there seems no $k$ such that $\{5^n-2^n \bmod k \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cap\{n^2\bmod k\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}=\emptyset$.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The only $n$ that yields a perfect square is $2$ in the Pythagorean Theorem and the number $2$ is not part of any Pythagorean triple. For this equation, the only solution is $n=0$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Checking things modulo $5$ you can see that $n$ has to be even, as $2$ is not a square (and hence so are all odd powers). So say $n = 2m$. Then we can write
$$5^n - 2^n = 5^{2m} - 2^{2m} = (5^m - 2^m)(5^m + 2^m).$$

Assume there exist $n$ such that we get perfect squares here. Then there is a minimal such $n$, that (due to laziness) we will in the following simply call $n$.
Any prime that divides $5^n - 2^n$ must divide it to an even power of at least two (quickly exclude the case $5^n - 2^n = 1$ for completeness sake please). But if all these primes also divide $5^m - 2^m$ to an even power, then $5^m - 2^m$ is also a perfect square, a contradiction to the assumption that $n$ is minimal.
That means that there must exist a prime divisor $p$ of $5^n - 2^n$ that divides both $5^m - 2^m$ and $5^m + 2^m$.
But then $p$ also divides the difference of the two, which is $2^{m+1}$, so $p = 2$.

But $5^n - 2^n$ is always odd, so $p = 2$ is not possible. Hence, we have found a contradiction to the assumption that any such $n$ exists.

Comment: Nice and clean.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is odd and greater than $1$ then $5^n-2^n\equiv 5\pmod{8}$, so it cannot be a square. If $n$ is even then $5^{2m}-2^{2m}=a^2$ leads to a primitive Pythagorean triple $(a,2^m,5^m)$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD all the primitive Pythagorean triples involving a power of $5$ as greatest element depend on the real and imaginary part of $(2+i)^{2m}$. The real part is always odd, while the imaginary part $a_m=\text{Im }(2+i)^{2m}$ fulfills
$$ a_{m+2} = 6a_{m+1}-25 a_{m} $$
such that
$$ \nu_2(a_m)\leq \nu_2(m)+1. $$
It follows that, apart from the first cases, which can be checked by hand, $a_m$ cannot be equal to $2^m$ and there is no square of the form $5^n-2^n$.

Answer (score -4):

One might note that $5^n-2^n$ is a base, and every new value of $n$ brings a new prime, previously not before seen.  If some prime $p$ divides $5^n-2^n$ then it divides $5^{pn}-2^{pn}$ an additional time.

So $5-2=3$ which is not square.  So we replace $n$ with $3n$, to get $5^3-2^3 = 3^2 13$.  But the 13 is not square, so we have to replace $n$ with $13n$.  Here we now introduce two very large coprime numbers, of which the larger is a multiple of 13.

It runs away as a power of exponentials.

Comment: How do you show in the first line that $(5^n-2^n)$ has a prime divisor that doesn't divide $(5^i-2^i)$ for $i<n$?

Comment: Because it's an algebraic base 5/2.  See https://numberbase.fandom.com/wiki/Algebraic_Bases  where i start writing this up.  There is a new factor that does not divide any lesser value, in the size of $5^{\phi(n)}$, the euler totient power.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I really don't see how this works. I agree that it works for $(5^n-2^n)$ up to at least $n=36$ [(link)](https://justpaste.it/3fks3) (beyond which, the numbers become too large to quickly factor) but the new factors are not all 'in the size of $5^{\phi(n)}$' or even the same order of magnitude. For $n=14$, we have a new factor of $1597$ but $5^{\phi(14)}=15625$. Or is this an asymptotic relation? Do you have any links to published proofs about this or is it all original work?

Comment: The factor that appears at $n=14$ is 11179, which is 7*1597.  The values of $5^n-2^n$ is cyclic over a period of 14, reletive to mod 49, but a period of 2 relative to mod 7.  

If you take the fractions 0/n to (n-1)/n, these will reduce according to the common factors of d/n.  Fractions that don't reduce, like 1/m, will only occur when $m\mid n$.  The new factors are then the product of $5 - 2 e^{2\pi\mathrm i * m/n}$  over m coprime and smaller than n.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification. Maybe you could add that to your answer and the numberbase.fandom page because I don't think it's obvious.

Comment: Consider $5^n-2^n$.  For a lesser value, it is possible to multiply through by a power of 5, so that the first power matches.  So you have $(5^n-2^n) - (5^m-2^m).5^{n-m}$,  Any common divisor must divide this too, so we get $2^m(5^{n-m}-2{n-m})$.  There is no common divisor in 2^m, so we can use a process to say if there is a common divisor of $5^m-2^m$ and $5^n-2^n$, it also divides $5^a-2^a$, where $a=\gcd{m,n}$, regardless of whether these numbers are composite or prime.  So m=14, n=15, share only 3 as a common dividor.

Comment: Well, it's known (and called Zsigmondy's theorem) that for coprime $a$ and $b$ ($a>b$) and positive integer $n$ there is a prime $p$ such that $p\mid a^n-b^n$ but $p\nmid a^k-b^k$ for $k<n$ unless $n=1,2,6$. For more details see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem

Comment: However, the proof requires knowledge of properties of the cyclotomic polynomials and doesn't correspond the level of this problem.